# how to run asp.net project on iis real server windows 2008

Tags: asp.net

HI,

i developed application in Visual Studio... ASP.NET project with master.page. I do it on my notebook and now I want put it on my server... i copy all files and give it to wwwroot directori in iis7 on my windows server 2008, but when i try start ist it wrote:

---

Runtime Error
Description: An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine.

Details: To enable the details of this specific error message to be viewable on remote machines, please create a  tag within a "web.config" configuration file located in the root directory of the current web application. This  tag should then have its "mode" attribute set to "Off".

Notes: The current error page you are seeing can be replaced by a custom error page by modifying the "defaultRedirect" attribute of the application's  configuration tag to point to a custom error page URL.

---

maybe it is stupit question becouse, all what i do is only copy files from project.. So please How can i put my asp.net project (web page) on server????

Thanks lot

PS: sorry for my englis i will work on it. :)

Eddy

Comment: you need to know more about the error, do as the yellow screen of death says, add that line to your `web.config` first and see the detailed error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to share the wwwroot folder, and create a publish configuration for your server's shared folder within Visual Studio.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20yh9f1b(v=vs.80).aspx